# Simple PHP Budget

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a simple budget form. What I need is that if some item is checked the system adds the price of these item (and if unchecked that item again substract it's price of the total).

```
<form name="myform" method ='post'>
<input name="item" type="checkbox" value="flowers"/>
<input name="item" type="checkbox" value="animals"/>
</form>
```

And what I want is something like

```
if (item[1].checked) $total_price = $total_price + item[1];
```

And likewise

```
if (item[1].unchecked) $total_price = $total_price - item[1];
```

Comment: I'm just lost! How can I make an PHP form and add or subtracting to a variable to can send it on submit? Have you any idea?

Comment: I think you need to study PHP a bit more before tackling this problem. Find a good book on the subject or go through some online tutorials.

Comment: Preferably the book. Online tutorials will lead you astray.

Comment: The unchecked part where you lower the price looks *scaaaaary*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example of how you might implement the above. I have not tested it, but it is something to get started with.

```
<?php

$price_list = array(
    'animals' => 100,
    'flowers' => 50
);

// Has data from form been posted back?
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $total_price = 0;

    foreach ($_POST['item'] as $item) {
        // Is price available for item?
        if (isset($price_list[ $item ]))
            $total_price += $price_list[ $item ];
        else
            throw new Exception('Invalid item: ' . $item);
    }

    echo 'Total Price: ', $total_price;

    // End script before form is shown again.
    die;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Item Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input id="itemFlowers" name="item[]" type="checkbox" value="flowers"/>
        <label for="itemFlowers">Flowers $<?php echo $price_list['flowers']; ?></label>
        <input id="itemAnimals" name="item[]" type="checkbox" value="animals"/>
        <label for="itemAnimals">Animals $<?php echo $price_list['animals']; ?></label>

        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! This works!! But there is any way to give the total without submit? Give it as you check or uncheck?

Comment: @JNestudi the same processing would need to be done with JavaScript instead of PHP. Just use a button input type (instead of submit) and place the count into a DIV.